# Flutter Build for Tessaract Package iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, ios-simulator

I am using Tessaract Package (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tesseract_ocr) for my flutter app and facing this issue.

```
   Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Could not find module 'SwiftyTesseract' for target 'arm64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: x86_64-apple-ios-simulator, x86_64,
```

For me I am a Flutter developer and have a very small idea about iOS native things! Can somebody give me any idea to solution to above error what is this for and what does it mean?

How to set the archtecture for my simulator through xCode or Android Studio?
Will it work on real device, and will not be a blocker for me!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you launch your app on simulator through XCode or by calling flutter run? If you're using XCode do you open `Runner.xcodeproj` or `Runner.xcworkspace` to launch your app?

Answer (score 1):

In this case it is not possible without using a translation layer (see jeann0t's answer). Let's consider the error message:

```
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Could not find module 'SwiftyTesseract' for target 'arm64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: x86_64-apple-ios-simulator, x86_64,
```

What it says is that there are no libraries for your M1-based Mac (arm64) but only for the older Intel-based ones (x86_64).

If you look on the official page for the project (https://github.com/SwiftyTesseract/SwiftyTesseract) you will see this notification which confirms it:

[image: LINUX and MACOS ARM64 are inaccessible]

This is likely due to the fact that the package has been marked as abandonware for the last 2 years. If you really want to run this code in your emulator without using a translation layer you might want to bring attention to the project and see if someone is willing to make it ARM64-compatible (on a contractual or volunteer basis) and either submit a pull request for the code changes on the original repo or simply fork it to be actively maintained.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Rosetta :

• Close Xcode

• Right-click it in your Applications directory

• Click `Get Info`

• Check `Open using Rosetta`.

Your simulator builds should then use the x86_64 arch.

What Louis-Eric wrote about the package being deprecated is still relevant though, and as the deprecated repo recommands, you should consider using Apple's native [Vision API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision), specifically [Text Recognition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/recognizing_text_in_images).